# Django Rest Framework ,logic of Like button for blog posts

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework project, users can post,comment any post and like any post. I can't figure it out the logic in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    body=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commet_post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body

class Like(models.Model):
    like_post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Please, elaborate the point of problem. I can see your model. But cannot what problem you are facing and why?

Comment: I don't know how to increase the like count whenever user click like button,should I use ManyToMany relationship field here ?

Comment: Nope. Like model will have a one-to-one relationship with User and Post model. You can count likes by a query such as: Like.objects.filter(like_post=post.id).aggregate(Count('pk'))

Answer (score 1):

You could make two endpoints for like: 1) for create & 2) for delete. Whenever someone clicks on the like button, it will hit the create endpoint and create a Like object. When someone clicks on unlike, it will hit the delete endpoint and delete the object. Like model will have a one-to-one relationship with User and Post model. You can count likes by a query such as: `Like.objects.filter(like_post=post.id).aggregate(Count('pk'))`